# Completeness + Totally Bounded vs Compactness for subsets

Tags: general-topology

*We know that*

> A metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded.

*Does this hold for its subsets? I mean, is a totally bounded subset of complete metric space a compact set?*

Comment: If and only if it is closed.

Comment: You mean, the subset must be closed and totally bounded for it to be compact?

Comment: A subset is compact if and only if it is compact as a space, so again if and only if it is complete and totally boundend. Every subspace of a totally bounded space is totally bounded but for completeness, it has to be closed. Also, it is easy to prove directly that a compact subset has to be closed and that this is in fact enough.

Comment: But of course, what follows directly from the definition and what needs a proof depends on what definition of compact space and compact set you use.

Answer (score 1):

No, $(0,1)$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R$ is completely bounded (and the space is complete) but not compact.

A subspace $A$ of a complete metric space is complete (in the inherited metric) iff $A$ is closed. So if $(X,d)$ is complete, $(A, d_A)$ is compact iff $A$ is closed in $X$ and totally bounded.